# Dimension Attribute not showing up in Business Intelligence Dev Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, dimensions

So I have a database schema and now I need to create a Cube for Analysis Services. I am, however, having an issue with one of the columns.

Here is what I did:
1. Create the Data Source
2. Create the Data Source View
3. Create dimensions, and this is where the problem is...

So my database has 10 tables and most of them work fine except for one. One table 'CustomerSatisfaction' has the columns 'year' 'quarter' 'customerSatisfactionValue' and 'productID'. Now when I create dimensions from this table I can't see the 'quater' column.

Basically I use the create dimension wizard but on the 'Select Dimension Attributes' section of the wizard I can't see the 'quarter' column. Any ideas why this is? I really want 'quarter' to be an attribute but it doesn't seem to be working...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is quarter listed as a column in the data source view?

If so, open up the dimension designer and drag the attribute from the data source view (on the right) to the attribute list (left).

If not, you'll need to fix the dimension query / refresh the table column listing in the data source view.

Comment: Thanks! Any drawbacks or changes in behaviour between dragging the attribute and adding it in the dimension wizard? To answer your question, the column is listed in the data source view. I was able to add it by dragging but why would it not showup in the wizard?